# Como remover aspas em uma lista de strings em python

Tags: python

Estou tentando criando uma lista com identificadores numéricos para as letras do alfabeto..

A abordagem que utilizei foi a seguinte.

```
# Criando Index para as letras do alfabeto.

letters = list(string.ascii_uppercase)
idx_value = 0
indexAndLetters = []

for i in letters:
  if i != 0:
    idx_value += 1
    idx_add = str(f'{idx_value}:,"{i}"')
    indexAndLetters.append(idx_add)

print(indexAndLetters)
```

Utilizei um **for** para percorrer a lista com as palavras e uni com os identificadores em uma nova listar e o resultado saiu conforme o esperado.

```
['1:,"A"', '2:,"B"', '3:,"C"', '4:,"D"', '5:,"E"', '6:,"F"', '7:,"G"', '8:,"H"', '9:,"I"', '10:,"J"', '11:,"K"', '12:,"L"', '13:,"M"', '14:,"N"', '15:,"O"', '16:,"P"', '17:,"Q"', '18:,"R"', '19:,"S"', '20:,"T"', '21:,"U"', '22:,"V"', '23:,"W"', '24:,"X"', '25:,"Y"', '26:,"Z"']
```

Minha dúvida é como eu posso remover as aspas simples presentes em cada conjunto de identificadores e números?

exemplo: no lugar de ['1: ,"A"']  deixar somente [1: ,"A"].

Comment: Não vai consegui fazer isso dentro de lista essa sintaxe `[1:,"A"]` não é suportada pelo python. Teria que ser algo assim `["1:","A"]` ou converter em dicionário.

Comment: Certo, eu estava utilizando uma ferramenta incompatível com meu problema, obrigado!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A melhor forma é converter em um dicionário que assim se precisar de um "C" por exemplo é só "indexAndLetters[2]"

Para isso usaria essa forma:

```py
letters = list(string.ascii_uppercase)
indexAndLetters = {}
for index, letter in enumerate(letters, 1):
    indexAndLetters[index] = letter
```

Ou do jeito pythonico e divertido:

```py
indexAndLetters = {index: letter for index, letter in enumerate(list(string.ascii_uppercase), 1)}
```

Comment: Massa, funcionou.. Obrigado pela contribuição! Eu vou estudar a utilização de dicionários.

Comment: @MarcosAndré Não precisa criar essa lista `letters`, pois strings são iteráveis e podem ser usadas diretamente no loop. Ou seja, poderia usar direto `enumerate(string.ascii_uppercase, 1)`. Outra forma de fazer é usar o código ASCII das letras, e a função `chr` para converter para caractere: `indexAndLetters = { i : chr(i + 64) for i in range(1, 27) }`. Mas se vc quer índices numéricos sequenciais, é sinal de que provavelmente o melhor seria usar uma lista mesmo, em vez de dicionário (não ficou claro como vc vai usar esses dados, mas enfim...)